# Error install testacular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-runner

I am following the testatcular vide tutorial http://vojtajina.github.com/testacular/.

I installed nodejs and when I tried to install testacular with

`sudo npm install -g testacular` 
I get this error :

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/testacular
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/testacular
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch

> chokidar@0.4.0 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testacular/node_modules/chokidar
> node setup.js postinstall

npm ERR! error installing chokidar@0.4.0
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node" 
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
npm WARN /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
npm WARN 
npm ERR! error installing testacular@0.0.17

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testacular/node_modules/___minimatch.npm/package/minimatch.js'
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/adio/workspace/java/tutorial/angularJS/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-17-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "testacular"
npm ERR! cwd /home/adio/workspace/java/tutorial/angularJS
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testacular/node_modules/___minimatch.npm/package/minimatch.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testacular/node_modules/___minimatch.npm/package/minimatch.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testacular/node_modules/___minimatch.npm/package/minimatch.js'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:204:26)
npm ERR! error rolling back testacular@0.0.17 Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testacular/node_modules/___glob.npm/package/test'

npm ERR! chokidar@0.4.0 postinstall: `node setup.js postinstall`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node setup.js postinstall"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the chokidar@0.4.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the chokidar package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node setup.js postinstall
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls chokidar
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-17-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "testacular"
npm ERR! cwd /home/adio/workspace/java/tutorial/angularJS
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message chokidar@0.4.0 postinstall: `node setup.js postinstall`
npm ERR! message `sh "-c" "node setup.js postinstall"` failed with 1
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/adio/workspace/java/tutorial/angularJS/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

anybody ran into this problem ?

thanks in advance for help.

Comment: The logs are giving a few avenues to try, have you tried those?  eg "This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node" (your version -0.6.9- is relatively old). "Additional logging details can be found in.." etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess, is it happening on a Win7 machine 64 bits?

I got the same error and it was already reported on [testacular github](https://github.com/vojtajina/testacular/issues/46)

The only workaround I found was installing node.js 32 bits instead of 64 bits version.
I encourage you to post another comment on their github so maybe it will be reconsidered

Comment: Actually no. I use ubuntu 12.10. I installed NodeJS with sudo apt-get install nodeJS, but the lastest version of nodeJS that is installed was 0.6.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the versions as the error log suggests. On Ubuntu 12.10 install NodeJS with sudo apt-get install nodejs will result in installing nodejs 0.6, but you need nodejs version 0.8 to install testacular so I followed this tutorial to install nodejs 0.8

```
http://davidtsadler.com/archives/2012/05/06/installing-node-js-on-ubuntu/
```